# Mysql query select from different tables with inner join

Tags: mysql, inner-join

From tb_user tables which contains all the users, I'm trying to inner join other tables to match data for each users and select them all. But from tb_work_time tables, the over_time column has multiple data for each users. I would like to select only the data from give date.

Right now i have this code, which doesn't work well.. Is there anyway to improve this?

```
SELECT
u.emp_no, u.name, u.position, d.name as dept_name, u.activeYN, (SELECT over_time FROM tb_work_time wt WHERE wt.emp_no = u.emp_no AND wt.work_date = '20190306'),
CASE WHEN ui.updatedTime >= NOW() - INTERVAL 5 minute THEN 'Y' ELSE 'N' END connectYN
FROM tb_user u
INNER JOIN tb_work_time wt ON u.emp_no = wt.emp_no
INNER JOIN tb_user_dept ud ON u.emp_no = ud.emp_no
INNER JOIN tb_dept d       ON ud.dept_id = d.dept_id
INNER JOIN tb_user_info ui ON ud.emp_no = ui.emp_no
```

when I execute this query.. the result is this.
[image]

it just keeps searching and no result.

```
SELECT
u.emp_no, u.name, u.position, d.name as dept_name, u.activeYN, (SELECT over_time FROM tb_work_time wt WHERE wt.emp_no = u.emp_no AND wt.work_date = '20190306') AS over_time,
CASE WHEN ui.updatedTime >= NOW() - INTERVAL 5 minute THEN 'Y' ELSE 'N' END connectYN
FROM tb_user u
INNER JOIN tb_user_dept ud ON u.emp_no = ud.emp_no
INNER JOIN tb_dept d       ON ud.dept_id = d.dept_id
INNER JOIN tb_user_info ui ON ud.emp_no = ui.emp_no
```

I've made this code to work. But it is really slow. Is there anyway to make it faster?

Comment: In what way doesn't it work well?

Comment: @nick after executing the query, it just keeps searching and doesn't get the result

Answer (score 0):

Here are a couple of queries to try.  Neither of these are tested because no sample data was provided in the question.

```
SELECT
u.emp_no,
u.name,
u.position,
d.name as dept_name,
u.activeYN,
wt.over_time,
CASE WHEN ui.updatedTime >= NOW() - INTERVAL 5 minute THEN 'Y' ELSE 'N' END connectYN
FROM tb_user u
INNER JOIN tb_work_time wt ON u.emp_no = wt.emp_no
INNER JOIN tb_user_dept ud ON u.emp_no = ud.emp_no
INNER JOIN tb_dept d       ON ud.dept_id = d.dept_id
INNER JOIN tb_user_info ui ON ud.emp_no = ui.emp_no
WHERE wt.work_date = '20190306';
```

Use this version below if there is any possibility of an `emp_no` in the `tb_work_time` table having more than one row per `work_date`.

```
SELECT
u.emp_no,
u.name,
u.position,
d.name as dept_name,
u.activeYN,
ot.over_time,
CASE WHEN ui.updatedTime >= NOW() - INTERVAL 5 minute THEN 'Y' ELSE 'N' END connectYN
FROM tb_user u
INNER JOIN (SELECT emp_no, SUM(over_time) AS over_time FROM tb_work_time WHERE work_date = '20190306' GROUP BY emp_no) ot ON u.emp_no = ot.emp_no
INNER JOIN tb_user_dept ud ON u.emp_no = ud.emp_no
INNER JOIN tb_dept d       ON ud.dept_id = d.dept_id
INNER JOIN tb_user_info ui ON ud.emp_no = ui.emp_no;
```